# How to connect a MSSQL database from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, server, database, mssql

I am trying to connect a MSSQL database from a Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I am using FreeTDS to connect, by following this tutorial

[http://guywyant.info/log/206/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-from-ubuntu/][1]

I'm stuck with the final stage, after giving the following command :

```
isql -v MSSQL devuser 'devpass'
```

Ubuntu is giving me the following error :

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

How can I overcome this issue and connect the MSSQL database?

**Update 1**
My problem is half solved now. Driver has been found now. At this moment it is showing the following error.

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found
[IM003][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Host name unknown
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my problem is different. My problem is that, it is showing "Data source name not found".

Comment: OK, then, could you post the content of your `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini files`?  The problem lies there.

Comment: What did you change to achieve Update1?  In my experience, the message `Data source not found` can come from the fact that the file `odbc.ini` is not found or that some parameters in there are wrong. I once had such a message and I found out that the problem was in an inccorrect uid/password combination (it was to connect to MySQL, however).

Comment: I just reinstall everything from the beginning and go through every step of the tutorial very carefully. You are right I also think that, problem lies in the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files.

Comment: May i suggest to turn on the trace facility of unixODBC.  this can be achieved by adding the following to your odbcinst.ini:
 `[ODBC]
Trace = yes
TraceFile = trace_file_path`